# PostgreSQL backup help

Tags: postgresql, backup

In PostgreSQL backup, the file large ( more than 500 GB ) And I need to do daily backup.
Have any option, how I not need to backup all of the 50 GB plus the changes daily? Only download the big one once, and then just the changes?

Example:

Have 1 000 000 000 numbers in my database on 3 tables. And this is take 50 GB.
And I backup already today the 50 GB. And today add more 1 000 000 numbers. that extra 1 GB.
I just like to download the 1 GB and add the already downloaded 50 GB. Not again the 51 GB total. And next day again only the added extra data download and add the 51 GB backup.

I read something about WAL archiving system, that will help me? If yes, how? If not what any option IO have to resolve this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform file system backups (for example with `pg_basebackup`) rather than `pg_dump`, you can consider the archived WAL segments as incremental backup that records only the changes to the data. So you can perform a full backup less often and recover everything since that by replaying WAL. The downside is that recovering lots of WAL can take substantial time.

You could consider using pgBackRest, which offers differential and incremental backups. These should restore faster than replaying lots of WAL.

Comment: So you thing for me better option the pgBackRest? That also just backing up the changes, and then we can restore the whole thing ( if need) ?

Comment: Probably, yes. Although 50 GB is a small database; I am surprised that that takes so long for you.

Comment: This is just " number" the real database more than 500 TB and growing daily. You have any suggestion or one documentation how can I set up the pgBackRest? Using windows 10 and PgAdmin.

Comment: Move away from Windows.